# Selenium.WebElement.Text is returning blank using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, text, getattribute

I am currently trying to obtain some printed text from an automated test website after I have completed a form. The returned values are displayed to the user on the screen after submitting the form, but for some reason I cannot obtain 2 of the 4 text values with Selenium's WebElement, I have tried using `.Text` and `GetAttribute("value")`, and they both return blank. Yet the first 2 pieces of text returned, I am able to retrieve. Please see screenshot below along with the code.

[image: Code displaying blank text, along with the test site]

//Then I verify the form submitted

```
Constants.confirmationName = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#name"));
if (Constants.confirmationName.Text == "Name:QA Automation")
{
    Console.WriteLine(Constants.confirmationName.Text);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("We have a different name stored for you.");
}


Constants.confirmationEmail = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#email"));
if (Constants.confirmationEmail.Text == "Email:automation@hotmail.com")
{
    Console.WriteLine(Constants.confirmationEmail.Text);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("We have a different email stored for you.");
}

Thread.Sleep(2000);

//NOT WORKING
Constants.confirmationCurrentAddress = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#currentAddress"));
Thread.Sleep(2000);
if (Constants.confirmationCurrentAddress.Text == "Current Address :Cedars 2 ")
{
    Console.WriteLine(Constants.confirmationCurrentAddress.Text);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("We have a different current address stored for you.");
}

//NOT WORKING
Constants.confirmationPermanentAddress = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#permanentAddress"));
if (Constants.confirmationPermanentAddress.Text == "Permananet Address :63 Wheat Drive")
{
    Console.WriteLine(Constants.confirmationPermanentAddress.Text);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("We have a different permanent address stored for you.");
}
```

The code confirms the name that is printed, and I can see it returned, same goes for the email address, but the current address and permanent address both return blank, I've tried to add in wait times too, but to no avail.

The website in question is https://demoqa.com/text-box, if you fill in the fields, then click Submit, you will see the printed information underneath.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it's driving me insane!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the HTML for any other Elements that share the same Id of currentAddress and permanentAddress, I reckon this is the problem as it's likely finding that first element matching that Id and that element has no text (hence the empty string and no exception).

Your code looks fine to me, and the fact that email and name work correctly suggests your code is also fine.

try changing this

```
Constants.confirmationCurrentAddress = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#currentAddress"));
```

to

```
Constants.confirmationCurrentAddress = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("p#currentAddress"));
```

that should help narrow down and find the element you're looking for.

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much, the text box field above had the same CSS selector and so it was looking at the wrong entry.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

With in the [ToolsQA Text Box](https://demoqa.com/text-box) webpage once you click on the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button as the values of *Full Name* and *Email* are immediately rendered within `<p>` tags:

[image: Name]

You can use the [*.Text*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Text.htm) property to extract the *innerText* as follows:

```
Constants.confirmationName = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#name"));
if (Constants.confirmationName.Text == "Name:QA Automation")
{
    Console.WriteLine(Constants.confirmationName.Text);
}
```

---

But the values of *Current Address* and *Permanent Address* are not rendered immediately within `<textarea>` tags

[image: Current Address]

Hence, to extract the value of *Current Address* and *Permananet Address* instead of using the [*Text*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Text.htm) property you need to use [*GetAttribute("value")*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm) method as follows:

- To extract *Current Address*:

  ```
  Constants.confirmationCurrentAddress = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#currentAddress"));
  if (Constants.confirmationCurrentAddress.GetAttribute("value") == "Current Address :Cedars 2 ")
  {
      Console.WriteLine(Constants.confirmationCurrentAddress.Text);
  }
  ```
- To extract *Permananet Address*:

  ```
  Constants.confirmationPermanentAddress = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#permanentAddress"));
  if (Constants.confirmationPermanentAddress.GetAttribute("value") == "Permananet Address :63 Wheat Drive")
  {
      Console.WriteLine(Constants.confirmationPermanentAddress.Text);
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Apologies as I may be getting confused, but have you not just suggested something that I said I have tried to do above? I've tried using GetAttribute("value") and the exact same happens, the value is returned as blank. GetAttribute("value") doesn't work either for the name and email address options, but the .Text option does.

.Text works fine for the name and email address, fields but not Current Address or Permanent Address, so why would I need to change it over anyway?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you, I will have another look at it and will come back to you.

Comment: Unfortunately I still had the same issue, text is blank.